# Flink Failure Recovery: What if a stateless operator failed

Tags: apache-flink, flink-statefun

We know, Flink creates checkpoints for every stateful operator periodically, and when crashes happen, it can use the checkpoints to recovery the system. But I can't find any paper or document about the stateless operator in these processes --"the creation of checkpoints" and "the recovery of fault".Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Stateless operators have no state, so there's nothing to checkpoint or restore, so that's why they aren't discussed in the context of checkpoint creation or recovery.